# Not open popup for action

Tags: isis

I'm using Apache Isis v1.16.2. 
I created an edit action but when my action is invoked Isis opened the associated form into a popup. I tried to set the property isis.objects.editing to false but in this way the user have to edit each property and click 'Ok' for each one. Which action Isis call to create default edit form?   My goal is: the user open the form, edit all properties and click 'Save' once. Is there a way to do it? Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently the only way to do this is with an action that takes all the arguments for the properties that you want to change.

We do have a JIRA ticket to allow such an action be associated with a fieldset rather than a property, so that when invoked would "replace" the fieldset (similar to how, today, an action associated with a property temporarily replaces just that one property).

That said, the Apache Isis framework is not intended to be a simple CRUD framework (even though people often mistake it as that).  Rather than let the end-user edit all properties in a single operation, instead identify why the fields need updating.  This will lead to a richer domain model that encapsulates meaningful business rules, rather than being some sort of glorified spreadsheet.

Still, the Wicket viewer is extensible though.  If you absolutely need an edit form yourself, see http://isis.apache.org/guides/ugvw/ugvw.html#_ugvw_extending_replacing-page-elements.

Alternatively, for that particular use case, consider developing a custom viewer and leverage Isis' REST API.

HTH